# Overwiew over all created javadocs

Tags: spring-boot, javadoc

I am wondering, if it is possible to get an overview over all created javadocs for example like swagger.

I have written some javadocs for projections, since projections can not be seen in swagger. Now I want to give the frontend a possibility to see the projections with a description, therefore it would be usefull if there is a webpage or something where my javadocs are located.

Is such a thing existing for a spring-boot project?

Greetings Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I used the a tool in IntelliJ described here

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html

with this I was able to create a folder in my structure and save the desired onse there.